# How to find $p$ from $a$ and $b$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Its not homework, is aerospace science. For real.

How to find the angle $p$ if I know the angles $a$ and $b$. Note $a$ and $b$ are not Euler angles, but are the angles between the vertical and the projection.

Note: seems that $cos(p)=cos(a)*cos(b)$ does not hold....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A-BCDE$ be the square pyramid where $BCDE$ is the rectangle and $AB$ is perpendicular to the base and $\angle{CAB}=a$.

Then, from $\triangle{ABD}$, we have
$$AB=\cos p,\quad BD=\sin p.$$

From $\triangle{ABC}$, we have
$$AC=\frac{\cos p}{\cos a},\quad BC=\tan a\cos p.$$

From $\triangle{ABE}$, we have
$$BE=\cos p\tan b.$$

Finally, from $\triangle{BCD}$, we have
$$BC^2+CD^2=BD^2,$$
i.e.
$$\tan^2a\cos^2p+\tan^2b\cos^2p=\sin^2p,$$
i.e.
$$\tan^2 p=\tan^2a+\tan^2b.$$
Hence, we have
$$\color{red}{p=\arctan\sqrt{\tan^2a+\tan^2b}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ be the length of the vertical edge shared by $a,b,p$. Then $p = \cos^{-1}(h)$, so it suffices to find $h$.

Let $x$ be the horizontal edge of the bottom square.

Let $y$ be the other "diagonal" edge of the bottom square.

Then we have $\tan a = y/h, \tan b = x/h$, so $x = h\tan b, y = h\tan a$.

Now simply note that the edge with length 1 is the 3-dimensional distance between two points with coordinates differing by $x,y,h$ respectively - in other words,

$$x^2 + y^2 + h^2 = 1$$

But since $x = h\tan b,y = h\tan a$, we have
$$h^2(\tan b)^2 + h^2(\tan a)^2 + h^2 = 1$$
So
$$h^2((\tan b)^2 + (\tan a)^2 + 1) = 1$$
Hence
$$h = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\tan b)^2 + (\tan a)^2 + 1}}$$
and
$$p = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\tan b)^2 + (\tan a)^2 + 1}}\right)$$